# Web pages of certain domains take very long until they start to load via openvpn

Tags: openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server at home behind my provider's router with the correct port opened.

I'm connection via UDP from my mobile phone to my home VPN to use a private connection for visiting web pages.

Most pages load without any noticeable delay. Some pages, like heise.de show a white screen for some seconds and then suddenly load quickly.

This isn't the case when I'm at home on my PC which shares the same internet connection. I tried both simultaneously over mobile phone internet and the PC on the DSL line. Same results as when I'm on the road.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Slow DNS resolution?

Comment: DNS is more likely, but it might also be my related.

Comment: Most Browsers help you with identifiying the reason for the delay.

Comment: @DavidPostill: but then it would likely be slow on my laptop, too, which it isn't. I used Termux on my phone to do a `dig heise.de` while connected to vpn. It used 8.8.8.8 as DNS server and query time was 92ms